# Background color not changing JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I need help on Java Swing for GUI. I have included `frame.getcontentpane().setBackground(color.cyan);` to the code but frame background color doesn't change.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class LoginOne {

    private static JLabel lblUsr;
    private static JButton btnNext;
    private static JTextField txtUsr;
    private static JFrame frame;
    private static JPanel panel;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        frame = new JFrame("Home Page");
        frame.setSize(800,600);
        frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.cyan);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        panel = new JPanel();
        frame.add(panel);

        panel.setLayout(null);

        lblUsr = new JLabel("Username");            //Username Label
        lblUsr.setBounds(10,20,80,25);        
        panel.add(lblUsr);                    

        txtUsr = new JTextField(20);         //Username input field
        txtUsr.setBounds(80,20,80,25);       
        panel.add(txtUsr);                   

        btnNext = new JButton("Next");
        btnNext.setBounds(80,90,80,25);
        panel.add(btnNext);

        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556). 2) See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556) A log-in would typically be done in a `JDialog` or `JOptionPane`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `panel.setBackground(Color.CYAN);` instead.

Comment: I'm assuming this is necessary because the JPanel's bounds are automatically set to fill the whole JFrame?